Invoke generic extension method, with runtime know type as argument
I have a generic extension:
public static T Get<T>(this DataRow row, string columnName)
{
    if (row == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(columnName) || row.IsNull(columnName))
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
            return (T)(object)string.Empty;
        else
            return default(T);
    else
    {
        if (row[columnName].GetType() == typeof(T))
            return row.Field<T>(columnName);
        else
        {
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(row[columnName], typeof(T));
        }
    }
}

I want to use it with a runtime known type:
obj = new K();
var props = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
for (int i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
{
    if (row.Table.Columns.Contains(props[i].Name))
    {
        // props[i].SetValue(obj, row[prop]);                         
        props[i].SetValue(obj, row.Get<props[i].PropertyType>(props[i].Name));
    }
}

But i get:

Compiler Error CS0019: Operator 'operator' cannot be applied to operands of type 'type' and 'type'

How can i invoke generic extension when the type is know at runtime ?
I was trying this solution:
Generics in C#, using type of a variable as parameter
but with no luck - maybe because i'm using extension ?

Generics are more a compile time thing. How would you program against the returned type if its only  known at runtime? The generic here does not help you.

I don't see the point of this code. It's no different than row[columnName] as T. If you don't want generics don't use LINQ methods

If you want to create a concrete object from a DataTable, you can use LINQ's Select. Although a better option would be to use eg Dapper to load results directly as objects instead of making a copy of the results in a DataTable

If the intent is to map query results to objects by name, you can replace all of this code using AutoMapper.Data. You can also use Automapper's configuration mechanisms to create more complex mappings.

My Get<> method, helps me in conversions like: short => int, null => "" etc. And now i want to use it in maping method (DB => object) like in Dapper. But reading all answers i see, i've complicated it to much :)

The answer is: you cannot resolve a generic type at runtime. Generics are always resolved at compile-time. They are not dynamic!
But there is no point in wanting to use a strongly typed object at runtime, since the PropertyInfo.SetValue Method requires an object parameter anyway. In a dynamic scenario you can happily just work with your Get method returning an object and use it as is when calling SetValue.
The purpose of generics is to give you type-safety, but this can only happen at compile-time, since it is the compiler which gives you this safety by checking whether the static types are compatible with the assignments and operations you are performing on them. At runtime there is no type-safety and therefore there is no point in using generics.
change your method to:
public static object Get(this DataRow row, string columnName, Type propertyType)
{
    if (row is null || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(columnName) || row.IsNull(columnName)) {
        if (propertyType == typeof(string)) {
            return string.Empty;
        } else if (propertyType.IsValueType) {
            return Activator.CreateInstance(propertyType);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        object value = row[columnName];
        if (value.GetType() == propertyType) {
            return value;
        } else {
            return Convert.ChangeType(value, propertyType);
        }
    }
}

and change your call to
PropertyInfo prop = props[i];
prop.SetValue(obj, row.Get(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType));


I think overloaded version of Get (with additional parameter) is the best solution. Thanks!

I've found solution:
var mi = typeof(Extensions).GetMethod("Get", [typeof(DataRow), typeof(string)]);
var generic = mi.MakeGenericMethod(props[i].PropertyType);
props[i].SetValue(obj, generic.Invoke(null, [row, props[i].Name ]));

Extensions is the static class in which i've declared my extenstion Get method.

Now you used a generic without using what generics gives you (typesafety). You just made it more complicated then simply using a typically runtime solution for this. Look at your own code and think about why the signature of Convert.ChangeType is the way it is (non-generic).

This code is no different than row[columnName] as T. It seems there's a lot of confusion involved on what is part of ADO.NET, a non-generic library, what are extensions like LINQ-to-DataSet, and what is needed to create concrete objects from query results

What is the purpose of Get<T> returning a strong type when SetValue only wants an object?
